# XML format generation issue

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to generate an `XML` document using `XDocument`:

```
   public class BuildXML
        {
           static void Main( string[ ] args ) {
              XDocument doc = new XDocument(
                new XElement("FolioIdentifiers",
                new XElement("FolioId", "6798634B2F7")),
                                         //);

                 new XElement("DocumentAuthentication",
                 new XElement("ScannedDocuments",
                 new XElement("ScannedDocument",
                 new XElement("DocumentType", "AppliationForm")))));

        doc.Save("C:\\document.xml");
```

When I run it, I get this error:

`This operation would create an incorrectly structured document.`

Am I using a wrong format?

Comment: An xml document can only have one root element (not an array).  You code produces an array at the root level.

Answer (score 3):

XML Documents can only have a single root node. In your case, you have two: `FolioIdentifiers` and `DocumentAuthentication`. If I tweak your formatting, it becomes easier to see.

```
public class BuildXML
{
    static void Main( string[ ] args )
    {
        XDocument doc = new XDocument(
            //At root level
            new XElement("FolioIdentifiers",
                new XElement("FolioId", "6798634B2F7")),

            //Also at root level (BAD! - this is what causes the incorrect structure error)
            new XElement("DocumentAuthentication",
                new XElement("ScannedDocuments",
                    new XElement("ScannedDocument",
                        new XElement("DocumentType", "AppliationForm")))));

        doc.Save("C:\\document.xml");
    }  
}
```

Comment: I get the same error message This operation would create an incorrectly structured document.

Comment: @ITDeveloper - I only restructured the format of your current code to help show why it's incorrect, I didn't change it. You need to decide whether you want a document of `FolioIdentifiers` or `DocumentAuthentification`. You can't do both in the same document unless you surround them with a **single root node**.

Comment: @Broots Waymb : There is nothing wrong with the nesting of the XElements.  Your comment is wrong : //Also at root level (BAD! - this is what causes the incorrect structure error)

Comment: @jdweng - How so? OP did not give the actual intended structure of the document, so I'm simply explaining *why* what he has is wrong, rather than assuming that `FolioIdentifiers` should be the root (although it seems likely the case). With OP's current code, `FolioIdentifiers` and `DocumentAuthentication` are both at root level (i.e. there is no true root), so I don't understand why my comment is incorrect...

Comment: With a new XElement you will never get a "structure error" if the code compiles.  You may get a schema error if the results doesn't conform.  I'm interpreting a structure error if the open and closing tags do not align and not a schema check.

Comment: @jdweng - The "incorrect structure" error is not my wording. I just took part of the error from when the code is run ("This operation would create an incorrectly structured document"). Regardless of terminology, it would result in invalid XML if it was able to run successfully. A surrounding root node would fix the issue (similar to in the duplicate JSteward linked), as would your solution.

Comment: @Broots Waymb : Try the code that is posted.  It only creates one element at the root, not an array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187583/discussion-between-broots-waymb-and-jdweng).

Answer (score 0):

The error is simple to resolve by making "FolioIdentifiers" the root element so you do not have an array at the root.  It can be solver by just moving the parenthesis :

```
             XDocument doc = new XDocument(
                new XElement("FolioIdentifiers", new object[] {
                new XElement("FolioId", "6798634B2F7"),
                 new XElement("DocumentAuthentication",
                 new XElement("ScannedDocuments",
                 new XElement("ScannedDocument",
                 new XElement("DocumentType", "AppliationForm"))))}));
```